# How do I test if the emulator is running?

Tags: javascript, firebase-tools

I am connecting to my storage emulator with the following code:

```
const firebaseApp = initializeApp(appConfig.firebase)
storage = getStorage(firebaseApp)
connectStorageEmulator(storage, 'localhost', 9199)
```

This works fine when the emulator is running. It also works fine when the emulator is NOT running! if its not running I want to do something else like this:

```
if (emulatorIsConnectedAndEmulatorIsRunning) {
  // do something
} else {
  // do something else
}
```

How can I detect whether the emulator is running or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After doing a little bit of research and testing I found out that the firebase emulator hub waits for the functions and storage to start so you could do:

```
axios.get(`http://localhost:4000/`)
```

And if it returns 200 the functions, storage is up.

Answer (score 0):

This is AN answer, not necessarily the best answer and I would appreciate other answers.

Basically, I am not just emulating storage but also cloud functions.

I've made a cloud function like this:

```
export const ping = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  res.json({ ping: 'pong' })
})
```

So in my code I just ping this endpoint. For example:

```
axios.get(`http://localhost:5001/${storageBucket}/us-central1/ping`)
```

If it responds 200 then the function emulator is running (and given my setup this also means the storage emulator is running).